# Android screen recording prompt

Tags: android

In Android 9, there's a "Don't ask again" option in the allow screen recording prompt, but in Android 10 and above, there is not. How can I enable this option or make it so I don't have to click "Start Recording" every time?

I have no idea what to try to fix the issue.

Comment: AFAIK, what you are seeking is not an option, sorry.

Comment: i know its not an option thats what i asked that how can i get that option back

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to get that option back.

Comment: well thats annoying can you try finding from google for me i tried but didnt find anything because i dont know what words to use english isnt my first language